# Wordpress - Email sending twice

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress page that is just sending an email The most basic form of this page looks like the following:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    wp_mail('my.email.addres@somedomain.com', 'TEST', 'Should only send once.');
  } 
?>

<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
  This page is to test the double get/post. Here 3.
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send email" />
</form>
```

The page has three plugins: Exec-PHP, Hupso Share Buttons for Twitter, Facebook, & Google+, and WordPress SEO (Yoast). I need Yoast on my site. However, this plugin seems to be causing the double-post issue. If its included, wp_mail sends the email twice. If Yoast is not included, the email is only sent once. I have no idea how to get past this.

Does anyone know why my email is sending twice instead of only once as it should be? I need to figure out how to only send the email once.

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but you can try adding an `onclick` attribute to your `<form>`: `... onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Form sending...';this.form.submit();"`.

Comment: try changing the name of submit to something else ( just for giggles)

Comment: I've run into this in the past.  My solution is to have a hidden field called "submitting", and have that value="0".  When the submit button is pressed, set the value to "1", and check that on the recieving page.

Answer (score -1):

Here i think wp_mail function is calling two times check the if condition how many time you are getting under the if condition if submit button is pressed.

like this you can check.

```
<?php
$i=1;
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    wp_mail('my.email.addres@somedomain.com', 'TEST', 'Should only send once.');
    $i++;
  } 
  echo $i;
?>
```